# Why Babel is still used on Node API projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs

Looking at some boilerplate's projects on github like:
https://github.com/KunalKapadia/express-mongoose-es6-rest-api
https://github.com/kylealwyn/node-rest-api-boilerplate

Some of them still use Babel. Node already supports almost all new features on ES2016 and ES2017 (Except Experimental). The only thing left is Modules. There is another reason to use Babel on Node projects?

Comment: *"Looking at some boilerplate's projects on github..."* Examples?

Comment: I do not think node has 100% coverage of ES6, think it is like 99% on the nightly channel. And are these templates also returning code to run in browsers which do not have ES6?

Comment: Aren't modules reason enough?

Comment: On example - does node.js stable (6.10 currently) support async/await yet?

Comment: @JaromandaX: The OP asks about "ES6" (e.g., ES2015). `async`/`await` aren't ES2015 or even ES2016. They will be in ES2017. But looking beyond the OP's "ES6" thing, sure, support for The Next Thing would be one reason a project might use Babel.

Comment: yeah, I took ES6 to mean "the next thing" ... because ES6 is not a thing, it's ES2015

Comment: @Jaromanda X LTS version doesn't support async/await, last stable version does, so I guess that is why they include babel on boilerplates. I am using v7.7.3 that support most ES2017 features. So not sure if I should do it only for modules

And sorry I was trying to refer to ES2016/2017.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://github.com/KunalKapadia/express-mongoose-es6-rest-api

Comment: @DavidRivera: To improve the question, use the "edit" link on the question. Also note the plural on "examples." :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you, modified it a little. Also made me notice that there are more projects not using it that what I originally thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your Node engine version, so simply check [Node Green Project](http://node.green/), You'll see how much Node covers ES6,7 and....

However, I would mention this that sometimes you are going to use Node Version 4 deliberately, for instance, when you want to deploy to AWS Lambda, you should set your project engine to 4 and in this case, you need Babel if you are coding in Fully ES6.